# Magento custom column in quote table not store value

Tags: magento-1.9, quote

im creating new column in quote table by using this line

```
$installer->run("ALTER TABLE `{$installer->getTable('sales/quote')}` ADD `excl_price` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 ;");
```

im saving value to column excl_price

```
$quote->setExclPrice(0);
```

but it not store value

can anyone help?

Comment: try re-index once.

Comment: not work .. im using magento 1.9.3.9

Comment: Have you tried with using $quote->setData('excl_price',0);

Answer (score 0):

Check your module have permission in config.xml ! Example.

```
          <my_module_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </my_module_write>
        <my_module_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </my_module_read>
       </resources>
```